# Is there a g++ equivalent to Visual Studio's __declspec(novtable)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, compiler-construction

Is there a g++ equivalent to Visual Studio's `__declspec(novtable)` argument?

Basically, in a pure virtual base class the `__declspec(novtable)` argument can be used to suppress the creation of a vtable for the base class as well as vtable initialization/deinitialization code in the contstructor/destructor respectively. E.g.,

```
class __declspec(novtable) PureVirtualBaseClass
{
    public: 
       PureVirtualBaseClass(){}
       virtual ~PureVirtualBaseClass() = 0;
};
```

See [Paul DiLascia's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301398.aspx) for more info. Also see my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801258/does-using-declspecnovtable-on-abstract-base-classes-affect-rtti-in-any-way).

Comment: Just curious: It seems to me that discarding the vtable for PureVirtualBaseClass is a microoptimization, and generally a very small one at that.  What's the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: Read DiLascia's article, he covers the reasons for wanting to do this better than I can.

Comment: Also, found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky.aspx today on MSDN where they suggest there can be a significant reduction in program size using __declspec(novtable).

Comment: Wouldn't whole program optimization let the compiler remove the vtables for any classes that aren't instantiated anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is one -- if there was, it would be listed under the [type attributes page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) of the GCC manual.  GCC uses type attributes to add extra annotations to types (such as alignment and padding), but there is no type attribute equivalent to `__declspc(novtable)` listed there.

I also don't see any compiler flag in the [command line options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) relating to this optimization.

Comment: It's been a while. Does this answer still apply?

Comment: I believe nowadays gcc has the
-fdevirtualize
switch which is in the -O2 optimization

Comment: @Dave No, according to the documentation on `-fdevirtualize` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fdevirtualize , that is a completely different optimization.