# How is CONDITION_VARIABLE implemented?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, wait, condition-variable

A longer version of the title question would be:

> On my machine, `sizeof(std::condition_variable)`  is 72 bytes.
> What are these 72 bytes used for?

*Note: The size of `std::condition_variable` depends on the implementation. Some examples sizes are given in **Appendix A.***

To understand how `std::condition_variable` works, I am satisfied to understand `wait`, `notify_one`, and member objects. I will start with `wait`. `wait` with a predicate is given below.

```
    template <class _Predicate>
    void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& _Lck, _Predicate _Pred) { // wait for signal and test predicate
        while (!_Pred()) {
            wait(_Lck);
        }
    }
```

The above `wait` calls the no-predicate `wait`.

```
    void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& _Lck) { // wait for signal
        // Nothing to do to comply with LWG-2135 because std::mutex lock/unlock are nothrow
        _Cnd_wait(_Mycnd(), _Lck.mutex()->_Mymtx());
    }
```

This wait calls `_Cnd_wait` on `_Mycnd()`. `_Cnd_wait` is found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/cond.cpp#L56).

```
int _Cnd_wait(const _Cnd_t cond, const _Mtx_t mtx) { // wait until signaled
    const auto cs = static_cast<Concurrency::details::stl_critical_section_interface*>(_Mtx_getconcrtcs(mtx));
    _Mtx_clear_owner(mtx);
    cond->_get_cv()->wait(cs);
    _Mtx_reset_owner(mtx);
    return _Thrd_success; // TRANSITION, ABI: Always returns _Thrd_success
}
```

`_Cnd_t` is a pointer to a `_Cnd_internal_imp_t` .

```
using _Cnd_t = struct _Cnd_internal_imp_t*;
```

The struct `_Cnd_internal_imp_t` is defined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/cond.cpp#L14).

```
struct _Cnd_internal_imp_t { // condition variable implementation for ConcRT
    std::aligned_storage_t<Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_max_size,
        Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_max_alignment>
        cv;

    [[nodiscard]] Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_interface* _get_cv() noexcept {
        // get pointer to implementation
        return reinterpret_cast<Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_interface*>(&cv);
    }
};
```

I am now looking at the line `cond->_get_cv()->wait(cs);`. To understand this line, I need to see `Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_interface`'s member `wait` function. This is a [virtual function](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/c76042bb32ecc838f40eac4374fc412b4c7374ef/stl/src/primitives.hpp#L27).

```
        class __declspec(novtable) stl_condition_variable_interface {
        public:
            virtual void wait(stl_critical_section_interface*)                   = 0;
            virtual bool wait_for(stl_critical_section_interface*, unsigned int) = 0;
            virtual void notify_one()                                            = 0;
            virtual void notify_all()                                            = 0;
            virtual void destroy()                                               = 0;
        };
```

**Edit 2**

`cond->_get_cv()` is a pointer to an abstract class `stl_condition_variable_interface`. At some point during construction, [`create_stl_condition_variable`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/c76042bb32ecc838f40eac4374fc412b4c7374ef/stl/src/primitives.hpp#L216) will be called to set the virtual pointer. The virtual pointer for this object will point to the vtable for either `stl_condition_variable_vista` given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/e86c643597dad5804c82f3b962c543c5f540ab83/stl/src/primitives.hpp#L75) or `stl_condition_variable_win7` given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/e86c643597dad5804c82f3b962c543c5f540ab83/stl/src/primitives.hpp#L148). The top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801258/does-using-declspecnovtable-on-abstract-base-classes-affect-rtti-in-any-way) stack overflow question explains some of the details.

In my case, the virtual pointer points to the table for `stl_condition_variable_win7`.

```
        class stl_condition_variable_win7 final : public stl_condition_variable_interface {
        public:
            stl_condition_variable_win7() {
                InitializeConditionVariable(&m_condition_variable);
            }

            ~stl_condition_variable_win7()                                  = delete;
            stl_condition_variable_win7(const stl_condition_variable_win7&) = delete;
            stl_condition_variable_win7& operator=(const stl_condition_variable_win7&) = delete;

            void destroy() override {}

            void wait(stl_critical_section_interface* lock) override {
                if (!stl_condition_variable_win7::wait_for(lock, INFINITE)) {
                    std::terminate();
                }
            }

            bool wait_for(stl_critical_section_interface* lock, unsigned int timeout) override {
                return SleepConditionVariableSRW(&m_condition_variable,
                           static_cast<stl_critical_section_win7*>(lock)->native_handle(), timeout, 0)
                    != 0;
            }

            void notify_one() override {
                WakeConditionVariable(&m_condition_variable);
            }

            void notify_all() override {
                WakeAllConditionVariable(&m_condition_variable);
            }

        private:
            CONDITION_VARIABLE m_condition_variable;
        };
```

So my 72 or 8 bytes are reserved to store a `CONDITION_VARIABLE` and the essense of `wait` is to call `SleepConditionVariableSRW`. This function is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepconditionvariablesrw).

END EDIT 2

**Appendix A**

The only member object of `std::condition_variable` is

```
aligned_storage_t<_Cnd_internal_imp_size, _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment> _Cnd_storage;
```

`std::condition_variable` contains the below member function which allows `_Cnd_storage` to be interpreted as a `_Cnd_t`.

```
    _Cnd_t _Mycnd() noexcept { // get pointer to _Cnd_internal_imp_t inside _Cnd_storage
        return reinterpret_cast<_Cnd_t>(&_Cnd_storage);
    }
```

`sizeof(std::condition_variable)` is given by the `sizeof(_Cnd_storage)`, which is defined in `xthreads.h`.

```
// Size and alignment for _Mtx_internal_imp_t and _Cnd_internal_imp_t
#ifdef _CRT_WINDOWS
#ifdef _WIN64
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_size      = 32;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_alignment = 8;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_size      = 16;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment = 8;
#else // _WIN64
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_size      = 20;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_alignment = 4;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_size      = 8;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment = 4;
#endif // _WIN64
#else // _CRT_WINDOWS
#ifdef _WIN64
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_size      = 80;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_alignment = 8;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_size      = 72;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment = 8;
#else // _WIN64
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_size      = 48;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Mtx_internal_imp_alignment = 4;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_size      = 40;
_INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment = 4;
#endif // _WIN64
#endif // _CRT_WINDOWS
```

**Edit 1/Appendix B**

I thought about this after posting the question, and I am not sure how to make it flow with the rest. `std::condition_variable`'s only member is

```
aligned_storage_t<_Cnd_internal_imp_size, _Cnd_internal_imp_alignment> _Cnd_storage;
```

which is interpreted as `_Cnd_internal_imp_t`. `_Cnd_internal_imp_t`'s only member is

```
std::aligned_storage_t<Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_max_size, Concurrency::details::stl_condition_variable_max_alignment> cv;
```

It is possible that `stl_condition_variable_max_size != _Cnd_internal_imp_size`. In fact, this implied in this [line](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/cond.cpp#L25)

```
static_assert(sizeof(_Cnd_internal_imp_t) <= _Cnd_internal_imp_size, "incorrect _Cnd_internal_imp_size");
```

This would mean that it is possible that some of the 72 bytes are "unused."

END EDIT 1

**Questions:**

1. `std::condition_variable` reserves 72 bytes for a `CONDITION_VARIABLE` (see Edit 2). What are these 72 bytes used for?
2. How could a `std::condition_variable` get away with fewer bytes? It appears as though on some machines `std::condition_variable`s are only 8 bytes big. See:

   ```
   _INLINE_VAR constexpr size_t _Cnd_internal_imp_size      = 8;
   ```

Comment: "*What are the 72 bytes of std::condition_variable used to store?*" You'll have to read the implementation to find out. "*How could a `std::condition_variable` get away with fewer bytes?*" It depends on the platform and implementation. That's what "implementation dependent" means.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"You'll have to read the implementation to find out."* The entire post is me going through the implementation until I got stuck.

Comment: @273K Debug and release give the same size of 72 bytes for me.

Comment: [`create_stl_condition_variable`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/e86c643597dad5804c82f3b962c543c5f540ab83/stl/src/primitives.hpp#L216) decides which concrete implementation to use. It checks `are_win7_sync_apis_available()` and if so, creates a `stl_condition_variable_win7` via placement new. Therefore, on win7, you get a `stl_condition_variable_win7`.

Comment: Remember that standard library implementations don't have to follow the same rules as user code, and they can reliably depend on compiler support. For one `wait()` could very well end up calling a function which has no visible implementation, which is instead intrinsically known to the compiler. Second. while it can be interesting to understand how standard features are implemented, you have to be careful when you try to apply that knowledge. Standard library feature implementations are allowed to "cheat".

Comment: The kind of answer **I'm** hoping for would go something like this: "32 bytes are used to store a 'vector'-like list of waiting threads, 32 bytes are used to store a 'vector' related to notification synchronization, and 8 bytes are used to store the number of ```notify_one```s still needing to be executed." This was my guess for how the 72 bytes would be used. I wasn't  sure how to communicate this in the OP.

Comment: _"32 bytes are used to store a 'vector'-like list of waiting threads_  -- there isn't anything like this in per OS sync object structures. `SRWLOCK` and `CONDITION_VARIABLE` have pointer size. All such lists are actually associated with OS thread objects. This allows `SRWLOCK` and `CONDITION_VARIABLE` to be very cheap and not needing non-trivial initialization/destruction. Size of the STL `condition_variable` / `mutex` is just unfortunate consequence of ABI compatibility with legacy implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `std::condition_variable` reserves 72 bytes for a CONDITION_VARIABLE (see Edit 2). What are these 72 bytes used for?

There was another implementation of condition variable that was backed by Concurrency Runtime (ConcRT). In Visual Studio 2012 it was the only implementation, but it turned out to be not very good.

Starting from VS 2015, there is better implementation backed by the actual `CONDITION_VARIABLE`. There is a polymorphism to create different implementations for different Windows versions, as `CONDITION_VARIABLE` is available starting Windows Vista, and a *complete* `SRWLOCK` is available starting in Windows 7. The polymorphism uses placement new rather than unions to hide the implementation details and to make the implementation conformant by [making it a standard-layout class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826969/why-is-stdmutex-a-standard-layout-class).

**So, there is a place for multiple implementations, out of which the ConcRT is the largest.**

Otherwise, `sizeof(CONDITION_VARIABLE) == sizeof(void*)`, as well as `sizeof(SRWLOCK) == sizeof(void*)`, though they aren't pointers internally. The rest of the size is wasted, if `CONDITION_VARIABLE` / `SRWLOCK` implementation is used.

Starting from Visual Studio 2019, Windows XP is no longer supported by the VS toolset (it is supported by VS 2019 by the ability to install VS 2017 toolset). So ConcRT dependency and the ability to create pre-Vista `condition_variable` was removed by [my PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1194). [A follow-up PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1325) removed ConcRT structure wrappers.

Starting from Visual Studio 2022, Windows Vista is no longer supported by the VS toolset either, [my other PR](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2317) to remove the `SRWLOCK` polymorphism is in flight.

Still due to the ABI compatibility between VS 2015, VS 2017, VS 2019, and VS 2022, it is not possible to reduce the size of `condition_variable`.

Getting rid of placement new in `mutex` constructor and fixing the conformance issue with having `mutex` constructor non-`constexpr` is also hard ([my attempt has failed](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2309)).

**So, VS 2019 and VS 2022 still have to reserve space for the ConcRT implementation, which is no longer used.**

With the next ABI breaking release of Visual Studio it is highly likely that the implementation of `condition_variable` will change.

---

> How could a std::condition_variable get away with fewer bytes?

`_CRT_WINDOWS` implementation never needed to support Windows XP, so does not have ConcRT fallback. Still it shares the implementation with the usual configuration, apparently for maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer, but it does provide more information.

The constructor of `std::condition_variable` calls a function that creates the implementation of the condition variable within `_Cnd_storage`

```
condition_variable() {
  _Cnd_init_in_situ(_Mycnd());
}
```

when `_CRT_WINDOWS` is defined, it appears that the data stored there is 2 pointers, or one pointer and one integer the size of a pointer; the first of which is probably a virtual function pointer (pointing at the `stl_condition_variable_interface`), and the other one is the state.

Depending on what the OS and libraries you are using provide, more or less machinery needs to be in the condition variable implementation.

That implementation may be in source code you do not appear to have access to.

https://github.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_vs2017bt_1416/blob/master/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/crt/src/stl/cond.c appears to be `_Cnd_init_in_situ`, which simply forwards to `Concurrency::details::create_stl_condition_variable(cond->_get_cv())`.

[Here](http://sandbox.hlt.bme.hu/%7Egaebor/STLdoc/VS2013/concrt_8h_source.html) is a VS2013 `Concurrency::detalis::_Condition_variable`.  It, however, does not appear to be what is created there (it has no virtual base).  It has two members:

```
void * volatile _M_pWaitChain;
Concurrency::critical_section _M_lock;
```

which may be similar to what is actually stored there (as it was a previous implementation for something similar).  The critical section is probably redundant for a `std` `condition_variable`, as it has an external mutex to work with.

What is in the `_M_pWaitChain` I cannot say, other than from its name.

All of this isn't complete.  I do know that modern condition variables know when they are signaled if they are holding the lock, and interact with which thread wakes up when the mutex is released; ie, low level internal to OS scheduling stuff.