# How do I suppress C++ vtable generation for pure virtual classes using G++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, virtual-functions, vtable

Supressing C++ vtable generation can be done in MSVC using the `__declspec(novtable)` attribute. However, it seems that [there is no equivalent attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787752/is-there-a-g-equivalent-to-visual-studios-declspecnovtable) for the GNU C++ compiler. The fact is that leaving the vtables for pure virtual classes unnecessarily links in `__cxa_abort()` and many others, and I want to avoid this happening because I'm programming for an embedded system. So, what should I do?

```
struct ISomeInterface
{
    virtual void Func() = 0;
};

class CSomeClass : public ISomeInterface
{
    virtual void Func();
}

void CSomeClass::Func()
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is something that will achieve a similar result:  `#pragma interface`.
`#pragma implementation` can override this, however.
http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/gcc/html/CPP_Interface.html

Answer (score 0):

The compiler flag `-fno-rtti` stops run-time type information generation.

In my experience with C++ on embedded platforms, this has prevented vtable compiler errors from occurring, suggesting it prevents them from being created (and consequentially, virtual functions won't work).