# NodeJS module compilation

Tags: node.js, makefile, g++, node-gyp, node-addon-api

I have a node add on module using [node-addon-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-addon-api) interface.

```js
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "mod",
      "sources": [
        "./src/index.cpp",
        ...
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        ...,
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        ...,
        "/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.5"
      ],
      'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
    }
  ]
}
```

This will produce a module that I can load from NodeJS with `require('./mod.node')`

What are the step to do this compilation from a makefile?

Answer (score 1):

If your Node addon uses a 3rd party library that you have to build, there are three ways to do it:

- Create a `Makefile` that launches the compilation of your 3rd party library and your Node addon (using the commands from my other answer), then link your addon with that library using the `libraries` section of the gyp file - this is the easiest choice
- Completely convert the 3rd party library to gyp - this is the best choice - I a maintaining a number of Node addons and I have created gyp building systems for them (I see Fortran in your gyp so you probably know about `netcdf` and `hdf5`) - but it is quite complex
- Convert your Node addon to classical `Makefile` or `cmake` - this is by far the hardest and it won't have any immediate benefits - you will have to reimplement `node-gyp` from scratch - something that even Node's core team is reluctant do to

Comment: This is getting better
* My approach is what you described in the first case.
* Could you expand the second a little bit. The projects you are mentioning are open source? If so, could you please link them.
* What are the reasons why Node's core team is reluctant, links again are wellcome.

Comment: https://github.com/mmomtchev/node-gdal-async - uses method 2

Comment: Then just create a `Makefile` with:
`project/lib/binding/addon.node: project/src/*.cc
  node-gyp configure && node-gyp build`

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. But now I was able at least to include the headers, so I think I can continue with the initial approach.

Comment: I will add it to the other answer

Comment: Please, don't. There is no point of keep adding multiple answers, it is better to write one good answer. The idea here is to summarize and write things in a way that is clearer and more concise than the documentation. I asked the question precisely because I was confused with multiple pages with similar text, and finding myself unable to find what I need.

Comment: @bob There are two questions here - how to build a node addon and how to integrate it with another build system - hence my two answers

Comment: ahh sorry, I thought you were going to post a third answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't use a `Makefile` with a `node-gyp` since `gyp` is a full-blown make in itself.

To build this you should call
`npx node-gyp build` *or* just `node-gyp build` if `node_modules/.bin` is in your path

You should also install it as a project dependency: `npm i --save node-gyp`

If you used `yeoman` to get this far, it already built it once for you automagically without requiring `node-gyp` - because it contains it in its package. You can call its copy from `/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js` but normally you should install it as a dependency of your project.

If you want to build this module from a `Makefile`, simply add this:

```
project/lib/binding/addon.node: project/src/*.cc project/src/*.h
  project/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp configure
  project/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp build -j max
```

In this case all your users will have to build it after installing from `npm`.

If you want to distribute it as a binary via `npm`, I also suggest you take a look at `@mapbox/node-pre-gyp` which is a replacement for `node-gyp` and automatically downloads prebuilt binaries from Amazon S3. If you prefer using Github Actions / Packages, you should take a look at `@mmomtchev/node-pre-gyp-github` of which I am the current maintainer.

Comment: This question is related to what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70671045/12750353). The kaldi project generate some makefiles using ./configure and they work if I have my code as a subfolder of the `src/` module. If I can extend them to compile a library compatible with node I am done.

Comment: I will post another answer, I think this one could be useful to someone else :-)